# How to debug why mocha isn't exiting?

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, asynchronous, mocha.js

I added a new endpoint and one of the tests for that endpoint doesn't exit. I was able to fid some questions about how to debug why a node process doesn't exit, but using these tools with mocha doesn't seem to work.

These are the tools I've tried so far:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/wtfnode
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/why-is-node-running
- https://gist.github.com/boneskull/7fe75b63d613fa940db7ec990a5f5843

I'm not saying that these tools don't work, nor that they can't work for debugging mocha, but I wasn't able to get anything useful out of them. If anyone knows how to make these tools work with mocha or knows of other tools that work with mocha, please let me know.

Comment: You probably already visited [this](https://boneskull.com/mocha-v4-nears-release/#mochawontforceexit), but just for sure.

Comment: @bigless I didn't see that link, but I tried what they are suggesting. The problem is that the only output I get is: `Forcefully terminating, unable to gather process info`

Comment: It sounds like `--exit` flag present..

Answer (score 0):

The way I ended up debugging, why my mocha test wasn't exiting, was by extracting the test with all the hooks and put it in a standalone file to be executed by itself.

By doing that I found the problem very quickly and could resolve it easily. I didn't even need `wtfnode`, although I was using it, because when the test was ran this way, `node` printed exceptions that had been swallowed by mocha. After addressing the exceptions the process exited as expected.

I can't think of a more tedious way of debugging your tests, so hopefully someone will come up with a better answer.